# Rails - Determine the day of the week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, dayofweek, weekday

So `DateTime.current` returns `Fri, 11 Mar 2016 19:34:10 +0000`.

How can I determine the day of the week. For example, if `DateTime.current` is Friday(just the day of the week, regardless of the date)?

`DateTime.current == DateTime.parse("Friday")` Won't work because `DateTime.parse("Friday")` returns `Fri, 11 Mar 2016 00:00:00 +0000` which is not the same.

How can I check whether only the date or only the time equals to a specific value?

Thanks in advance!

Basically I want to see if `DateTime.current` is not a weekend nor a  public holiday and is between office working hours

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ruby 2.1.1, the Date class has a `friday?` method

> Returns true if the date is a friday

First, require the `date` library

```
require 'date'
```

Then create a new date instance with the current date. Here's an example

```
current_time = Time.now
year = current_time.year
month = current_time.month
day = current_time.day

date = Date.new(year, month, day)
date.friday?
=> true
```

Depending on your coding preferences, you could DRY this up even more

```
date = Date.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day)
=> #<Date: 2016-03-11 ((2457459j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date.friday?
```

If you'd like to solve this without a Boolean method, (the ones that usually end in a question mark and return either `true` or `false`), such as when you're comparing to a database column, you can use the `Date#wday` method. Keep in mind, this returns a number in the range (0..6) with 0 representing Sunday. This means that you want to pass in 5 to check for Friday.

```
if date.wday == 5
  // Do something
end
```

Also, if you are working with business hours, it might be easiest to use the `business_time` gem

You can also include the `holidays` gem with `business_time`.

First, install the gems

```
gem install business_time
gem install holidays
```

Then require the gem

```
require 'business_time'
require 'holidays'
```

Find out if today is a workday

```
Date.today.workday?
```

> and is a holiday

You can now use something like this to determine if today is a holiday

```
Holidays.on(date, :us).empty?
```

> and is between office working hours

The definition of office hours varies from person to person. There's no set-in-stone answer. However, with the `business_time` gem, you can set configurations

```
BusinessTime::Config.beginning_of_workday = "8:30 am"
BusinessTime::Config.end_of_workday = "5:30 pm"
```

**Sources**

*Ruby*

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-wday

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-friday-3F

*Gems*

https://github.com/bokmann/business_time

https://github.com/holidays/holidays

Comment: Thanks but I need to write it from scratch, also I need to compare two DateTime objects, so boolean value won't really help me here!

Comment: what do you mean by write from scratch?

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like the following:

```
day = DateTime.now.strftime("%A")
```

This will return the day of the week with the full name, capitalized. You can also get the abbreviation like this:

```
day = DateTime.now.strftime("%a")
```

You can also use %u or %w to get the day of the week as an integer. Friday would be 5.

```
DateTime.now.strftime("%u") == 5 # True if Friday
```

You can check here for more capabilities:

[APIdock documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Answer (score 1):

Check this-

```
require 'date'
today = DateTime.current.to_date

if today.Friday?
  puts "Today is a Friday!"
end
```